# Python Create Series Of Text Menus- Classes/Objects or Decorator Functions?

Tags: python, object, menu, decorator

I am creating a series of text menus in Python. I've been told in Python conventions that I should only make classes/objects for data members that need to be maintained and manipulated. Going be this I am not sure.....would the below be appropriate or would creating a basic function and then decorating it according to which menu be better?

```
class Menu(object):
   def __init__(self):
      # Ideally, self._options would be an empty dict for the base class.
      # This is just for the sake of example.
      self._options = {'a': self.optionA,
                       'b': self.optionB}

   def handle_options(self, option):
      if option not in self._options:
         print "Invalid option"
         # re-draw
         return

      self._options[option]()

   def optionA(self):
      print "option A"

   def optionB(self):
      print "option B"


class SubMenu(Menu):
   def __init__(self):
      Menu.__init__(self)

      self._options = {'c': self.optionC,
                       'd': self.optionD}

   def optionC(self):
      # ...

   def optionD(self):
      # .
```

..

Comment: Python is still an object-oriented language. So, subclassing an abstract `Menu` class is just fine. Stick with simplicity. I see no reason to decorate a function. This is what inheritance is for.

Comment: Now that I think about it, with sub classing I don't need the subclass to inherit the options of the parent class since they will be different. Will this be wasteful efficiency wise? In that case functions with decorators be better?

Comment: Well, part of object-oriented programming is [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming), which is exactly what happens when a sub-class redefines a method and its behavior. There's nothing wrong with this, and it certainly should not be inefficient. However, if sub-classes are having to regularly redefine methods of their parent classes then you may have a design issue. One of the best features of OOP is that it promotes code re-use. Not that decorators are not useful, especially in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to have a `Menu` base class that only provides *behavior* -- such as presenting itself, dropping down menus, having attached menus pop to the right, hiding itself, etc.

Then have subclasses contain the actual data for each menu instance.